# Azure Search Hierarchical Search Field

Tags: search, odata, azure-cognitive-search

I am evaluating Azure Search for a project. The MSDN articles are having only Flattened schema structure. Below is an example scenario i am looking at.

The below is "Project" class having reference to List of "Question" class. And "Question" has it's own set of fields

```
public class Project
    {
        public Guid Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Owner
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<Question> QuestionList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool Disable
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

}

public class Question
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

> Below will be **Index Schema for Project**

- Id - Edm.String
- Owner - Edm.String
- Title - Edm.String
- QuestionList - Collection(Edm.String)

**Questions**

- Is it possible to specify each item in QuestionList has hierarchical data?
- Is it possible to Search only inside "Title" of "Question"?
- The only possibility i see is to create Index for "Question" separately and use it

The only point i see in MSDN relevant is the below paragraph and i can't make much sense of it

> Levels in faceted navigation
>
> As noted, there is no direct support for nesting facets in a
>   hierarchy. Out of the box, faceted navigation only supports one level
>   of filters. However, workarounds do exist. You can encode a
>   hierarchical facet structure in a Collection(Edm.String) with one
>   entry point per hierarchy. Implementing this workaround is beyond the
>   scope of this article, but you can read about collections in OData by
>   Example.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, Azure Search does not allow for hierarchical datatypes, and to search you would need to flatten the data as you did for the QuestionList field which you created as a Collection.  If you were asking how to also filter results based on items in this Collection, you can do that using OData Expressions such as $filter=QuestionList/any(t: t eq 'Question1') (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798921.aspx)

I think for your second question, you were interested searching only in "Title" **or** "Question", correct?  For this, you can use the SearchFields parameter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798927.aspx).

Liam

Comment: Thanks for update. For the question #2; "Question" field has 2 fields in it - "Title" & "Description". I wanted to specify in the SearchField search only inside Tile of each Question. Some thing like  **searchFields=Question.Title** . Is this valid?

Comment: @SridharVenkat did you find any alternative for that?

Comment: @eglasius, hierarchical datatypes we didn't go for it... but i did research initially, these urls might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff478141.aspx , https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/search-faceted-navigation/.

Comment: Thanks! the second link does show point to an approach for simple equality matches (including and/or of the fields) that works for complex types that have very few fields. Naturally we still have the direct match limitation of the Collection(string) support i.e. can't do range based searches or any other kind of complex expression when matching elements.